# How to push a viewController with a specific view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a 'firstController' and 'SecondController'.

In 'firstController', I have a 'navigationController' I would like to push to the "Second Controller", but I would like to specify the view. There are many views in the 'SecondController'.

How can I do that ?

Comment: SecondViewController *sVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];   [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:sVC animated:yes];

Comment: @Madhu it will push to the main view, i want to choose the view !

Comment: Firslty import the destinationView,You create the object for destination view controller and pass that object as parameter to - (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;

Comment: @Madhu yes, then how i specify the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a method, `initWithViewKey:(NSString *)viewKey`. An enum of some sort would work too. Then in the `initWithViewKey:` method, you could change the logic based on the value of the key.

Comment: doesn't work, still push to the main view of secondController

Comment: actually, I think you should store the value of viewKey in either an ivar or an @property. Then override the `loadView` method and set your own view based on the viewKey ivar. In loadView you are responsible for setting the view controller's `view` property.

Comment: ok problem solved, i didn't need to override loadView, just add a condition of the key in the viewDidLoad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call `initWithNibName:bundle:` with the nib name you want, or override the `loadView` method and set your `ViewController`'s view from there.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like below code**..

```
    YourViewController *vController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:(BOOL)YES];
[vController release];
```